# Laravel post data to function within the controller

Tags: php, function, post, laravel, controller

Currently my HomeController looks like this:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function getHome()
    {
        $scripts = Script::select('script.*', DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(vote.rating), 0) as rating'))
                    ->leftJoin('script_vote as vote', 'vote.script_id', '=', 'script.id')
                    ->with('tags')
                    ->orderBy('rating', 'desc')
                    ->orderBy('views', 'desc')
                    ->groupBy('id')
                    ->paginate(8);

        return View::make('home')->with('scripts', $scripts);
    }

    public function postSearch()
    {
        $input = array(
            'query'    => Input::get('query'),
            'sort_col' => Input::get('sort_col'),
            'sort_dir' => Input::get('sort_dir'),
        );

        $scripts = Script::select('script.*', DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(vote.rating), 0) as rating'))
                    ->leftJoin('script_vote as vote', 'vote.script_id', '=', 'script.id')
                    ->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $input['query'] . '%')
                    ->orderBy($input['sort_col'], $input['sort_dir'])
                    ->orderBy('views', 'desc')
                    ->groupBy('id')
                    ->with('tags')
                    ->paginate(8);

        Input::flash();

        return View::make('home')->with('scripts', $scripts);
    }

}
```

As you can see, I'm using (almost) the same big query twice. I would like to call the `postSearch()` function within the `getHome()` function and give the three parameters (query = '', sort_col = 'rating', sort_dir = 'desc') with it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan on using this frequently I would move this out of your controller and put it in your Model as a [Custom Query Scope](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes). This really doesn't have a place in the Controller even as a private function.

```
public function scopeRating($query)
{
    return $query->select('script.*', DB::raw('COALESCE(SUM(vote.rating), 0) as rating'))
                ->leftJoin('script_vote as vote', 'vote.script_id', '=', 'script.id')
                ->with('tags')
                ->orderBy('rating', 'desc')
                ->orderBy('views', 'desc')
                ->groupBy('id');
}
```

This could then be called like this

```
Script::rating();
```

Answer (score 1):

here are a few possibilities:

- write a `private function getScripts(...)` within the controller (not so sexy)
- add a `getScripts(...)` function on your Scripts model (so-lala sexy)
- create a [service provider](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages#service-providers) to encapsulate the model(s) and inject them into the controller